# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed (for discord Py bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hey I'm pretty new to coding bots in python, I've gotten this error for quite a bit and I don't know what's wrong, could someone help please.

```
cogs = [levelsys]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)

client.run("Token")
```

more of the error message:

```
         > & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/Bot/TheHubProjects/LevelSys/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Bot\TheHubProjects\LevelSys\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.run("Token")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 666, in start
    await self.connect(reconnect=reconnect)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 601, in connect
    raise PrivilegedIntentsRequired(exc.shard_id) from None
discord.errors.PrivilegedIntentsRequired: Shard ID None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000014FBE5BA280>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
PS D:\Bot> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/Bot/TheHubProjects/LevelSys/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request     
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Bot\TheHubProjects\LevelSys\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.run("Token")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001BD6BABA280>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: **Please reset your discord bot token, it is still visible in the edit history and may be used by anyone to take over your bot**.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, just reset it

Comment: I've mod flagged so that the revisions with the token can be redacted.

Comment: It's already reset but ty anyways

Answer (score 0):

I hope thats not your actual discord bot token? And you have "commands_prefix="-" its just "command_prefix="-"

Edit: i believe its in the loading cog, try putting your cog class in its own folder called cogs. This function gets all files in cogs folder with .py, removes the .py and load them. You arnt using the load_extension so hopefully this works, other than this it must be a error in the cog class or an error with the "intents="

```
# Load All Categorys in cogs folder
Import os
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
  if filename.endswith('.py'):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Comment: realized that too late I changed it already. the problem still happens

Comment: Could you edit with more of the error message? Your cog file has functions in it? (Not an empty class)

Comment: I'm using visual studio code so it's error message is not the most accurate but I'll add it anyways

Comment: The token is in the error message, if you havent reset it. Ikr using vscode and discord.py isnt fun

Comment: I should've really used pycharm, btw that's the old token but I removed it anyways

Comment: This didn't work for me but it's probably because I did something wrong, I think I'm going to try remake this in Pycharm, if it gives a more accurate error I'll edit the post.